# Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle when loading an npy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, load

Hi I am a new user to python and want to import a saved npy array. When attempting to load the npy array, I get the following error message. Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np

A = np.load('C:/Final Runs/lineTank.npy')
```

I receive these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 384, in load
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'C:/Final Runs/lineTank.npy' as a pickle
```

Comment: Are you sure that `lineTank.npy` is actually a binary npy file? Was it saved by `np.save` on the same system?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes it created using np.save

Comment: @user1985939 try to do: `np.load(open(r'C:\Final Runs\lineTank.npy', 'rb'))`

Comment: Thanks @SaulloCastro. I realized was right I created the .npy file using a traditional python method that did not work for reading it into numpy! <br>f = open("sparTank.npy", "w")  <br>try:  <br>      f.write(VRms_Tank)  <br>finally:  <br>    f.close()

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help guys. I realized @Joe Kington was right. The file was creating using the traditional python write to a file as opposed to numpy. This is what I had used (which didn't work):

```
f = open(Filename, "w")
try:
    f.write(a)
finally:
    f.close()
```

as opposed to using numpy's save, which works:

```
import numpy as np
np.save(Filename, a)
a = np.load(Filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to load the file into a string first, then numpy.load() the string.

Something like :

```
with f as file.open(filename):
  foo = f.readlines()
bar = numpy.load(foo)
```